# what is the name of this kind of query and difference between using them

Tags: c#, sql, linq

What is the name of these two kind of query?

```
return (from c in _dbRead.Domain
                where c.ID == ID
                select c).FirstOrDefault();

return _dbRead.Domain.Where(x => x.ID == ID).FirstOrDefault();
```

I mean let's say i call first one as "linq to sql query" what do i name the second query, ofcourse second one is also "linq to sql query" but what do i name the second query.

And please tell me, what's the difference between using them?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one uses the query expression syntax, while the second uses method syntax.

They are effectively the same thing: the compiler transforms the first version into the second (you can read more about this transformation process in [part 41](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2011/01/28/reimplementing-linq-to-objects-part-41-how-query-expressions-work.aspx) of Jon Skeet's [Edulinq](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/tags/Edulinq/default.aspx) series). There is no semantic or performance difference between the two.

Answer (score 2):

`x => x.ID == ID` in specific are called **lambda expressions**. Apart from that,there is no special names for such queries.

Answer (score 2):

The first version uses query-comprehension syntax, whereas the second uses extension methods. They are both forms of LINQ.